# What is the error in this code operator overloading?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class date 
{
   int day,year,month;
   int add,subt;

   public:
   date ()
   {
      day = 17;
      year = 2019;
      month = 3;
      add = 0;
      subt = 0;     
   }    

   void recent_date ()
   {
    cout<<"Recent date   :    "<<day<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year;
   }

   void adding ()
   {
    cout<<endl<<"How many days you want to go in a future  :   ";
    cin>>add;
   }

   date operator+()
   {
        date temp;
        temp = (day,month,year);
        day += temp.add;

        if (day > 31 && month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 ||month == 10 || month == 12)
           {
               temp.month++;
               day = temp.day - 31;
               year = temp.year;        
           }
           return temp;
   }
};

main ()
{
    date obj;
    obj.recent_date();
    obj.adding();
    obj=temp++;
    obj.recent_date();
}
```

I get a syntax error, and the program did not run.

I want to increment the date by accepting user input.
But, it does not run properly.

Can any one explain this code for me?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please include the exact error message.

Comment: i cant acces the operator overloading in a main.

Comment: What does this do? `obj=temp++;` I don't see temp defined anywhere

Comment: Please include the exact error message you've got from the compiler. Please be aware that `main()` is not legsl iin C++.

Comment: `date temp; temp = (day,month,year);` should be `date temp{day, year, month};`

Comment: You still have not provided the error message.

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) for more information on overloading the increment operator.

In short, these four operators are different:

```
operator+(T) // addition
operator+()  // unary plus
operator++() // prefix increment (++x)
operator++(int) // postfix increment (x++)
```

What you seem to want to overload is postfix increment.

Thanks to @BenVoigt for pointing that I skipped unary plus.

Comment: And there is also the `operator +()` which OP defined, which is "unary plus"

Answer (score 0):

You called `temp++` but never defined an operator to do that.

This uses *postfix increment*, which might look like this:

```
date operator++(int)
{
   // ...
}
```

My hypothesis is that you intended this instead of `date operator+()`.

Per mhhollomon's answer, you may wish to overload some other operators too, to get a robust interface.